# Artificial intelligence operating system

Tags: operating-system, artificial-intelligence

I agree that there are lot of operating systems out there but none which fully takes the capabilities of artificial intelligence(AFAIK) . I was looking for a final year project(undergraduate cs) and thought of this . But I dont know if the idea is solid enough(as i have really small ideas)

Basically the operating system will be built using Linux kernel and I thought of the following ideas to be built upon it

1. The os identifies the user who is using the system for e.g if the user is a small child , the os manages the theme accordingly be patient with the child , shows him/her fun ways to explore,etc
2. The os search capabilities are improved, for e.g if the user is programming a lot , probably it searches things in that domain .. etc
3. Adjusting brightness(similar to iphone ?? )
4. Probably integrate it with sound and video

I know these ideas dont look so solid for a final year project . Looking for suggestions . It may be related to the same question (or) suggesting a projects in the similar domains.

Thanks in advance

Comment: AI? it would be nice if more popular OS's took advantage of bit more Bayesian probability!

Comment: What you are describing is a graphical user interface *on top* of an OS. Sounds interesting though..

Comment: lol, after the numerous "Which programming language for AI?" questions I expected a "Which OS for AI?" question. Which keyboard should I use to program AI? Is a cable mouse ok or do I need cordless?

Comment: I recommend investigating related AI technologies first and finding Linux libraries you can use. Last thing you want is grabbing a topic and finding that it is a PhD-worthy enterprise. I suspect this will narrow down your choices quite a bit.

Comment: Why do you call this AI? This seems as usual preferences depending on user - just with multiple default values according to some user archetype. Do you call AI grabbing info from webcamera or usually used programs and then deciding the archetype?

Comment: You should probably notice this little lesson from history: the infamous [Microsoft Paperclip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant) that everyone loved to hate was built to use Bayesian algorithms (simple AI, in a sense) to recognise the user's activity and offer help, a bit like you're describing...

Comment: The OP should get serious,.that's if is really interested in AI

Answer (score 0):

In security field you have some good options, my suggestion is a integrated artificial immune system based on [Forrest's work](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.3258) that can look for unauthorized modifications on the system. For example, if you try to install bumblebee package and it try to remove /usr, the module block it and asks the user for confirmation.

Comment: Do you really understood the question.And what is artificial intelligence?